# Turn Ratio of a Transformer

Tags: transformer

Turn ratio is defined as high voltage to low voltage ratio as per IEEE standards.
Now my doubt is:
In 3 phase transformer,
Is it phase voltage ratio/or line voltage ratio?

Comment: 3 pase loads like motors or water heaters may be connected using wye or delta circuit. There are transformers for wye or delta circuit. For all these circuits, a load between two phases is exposed to the voltage between these phases. A load between one phase and neutral is exposed to the line voltage. In this 12 pulse rectifier [circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:12_pulse_bridge.png), a transformer with two sets of secondary windings is used, one set in delta and the other in wye circuit. The primary windings are connected in wye circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's voltage between terminals.

for a wye winding it's line voltage (to neutral) for
 a Delta winding it's phase voltage (between phases)

Answer (score 0):

[image] n refers to inductance² or voltage ratio of paired windings.

But if it is Delta(line-line) winding to Wye (phase-N) \$V_L=\sqrt 3 V_P\$ is used to correct the n turns ratio for voltage.

Comment: re-check your formula